# How to use pow() for equations and not ending with nan

Tags: c++, function, math

I've tried using double and long double but it shows nan, I also tried changing it to `float` but still wouldn't work, and I've changed it to a `long int` but the result is different from the calculator. [Using dcoder app, inputted numbers 1,2,3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs93y.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a, b, c;
    long double x1, x, num1,num2;
    cout<<"enter number\n";
    cin>>a>>b>>c;

    if(a&&b==0){
        cout<<"\nno solution";
    } else if(a==0){
        num2=-c/b;
        cout<<"\none root: "<<num2;
    } else if(num1<0){
        cout<<"\nno roots";
    } else{
        num1= pow(b,2) - (4*a*c);
        x= -b + (pow(num1,-0.5)) / 2*a;
        x1= -b - (pow(num1,0.5)) / 2*a; 
        cout<<"\ntwo roots\n" <<num1<<"\n"<<x<<"\n"<<x1;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: what do you expect from `if (a&&b==0)`; IMHO you are not doing what you think there

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings and pay attention to them.

Comment: idem for `          x = -b + pow (num1, -0.5) / 2. * a;
          x1 = -b - pow (num1, 0.5) / 2. * a;` you are missing parenthesis

Comment: and I guess it is  pow (num1, 0.5) not   pow (num1, -0.5)

Comment: Why even use `pow(num1, 0.5)`? `std::sqrt()` exists.

Comment: @OznOg in which one?

Comment: `pow(b,2)` can be written more easily as `b*b`  (albeit the result if of type `int`, not `double`).  Whether using `pow()` or not, most numeric operations can overflow, and you need to account for that (i.e. prevent the operations occurring that produce overflow).   You can't just assume that the compiler or standard library will simply recover from an overflow and give you the mathematically correct result.

Comment: well I guess you can take everybodys' comments and go fix your code :)

Comment: @OznOg because there is this exponent 1/2, and there are two equations, one is positive 1/2, and the other is -1/2, and Im not sure how to put them in the code

Comment: last one, you should use float for a, b, c, else you are performing some integral divisions that won't give you the expected result.

Comment: check the math https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula_and_its_derivation there are both square roots

Comment: @OznOg thanks for the help, the equation itself that was given to me was wrong indeed about the pow(num1,0.5),